# Extract everything between every string "Atribuição: "

Tags: r, regex

Here's my text:

```
teste <- "2ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – CRIMINAL (RECLUSÃO)\r\nAtribuição: Criminal – 8ª Vara Criminal (juiz 2)\r\nNovo Fórum: 
sala 203-B – fone: 3018-0835\r\n2promotoria@mpgo.mp.br  Vanusa de Araújo Lopes 
Andrade                       Resolução\r\n              
                                                               07/2016\r\n3ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – CRIMINAL (RECLUSÃO)\r\nAtribuição: Criminal – 
10ª Vara Criminal (juiz 2)\r\nNovo Fórum: sala 423 A - Telefones: 3018-0808 / 
0809 / 0810 / 0811\r\n3promotoria@mpgo.mp.br Mozart Brum Silva (Mozart Brum Silva 
atua em Resolução\r\n                       substituição na 64ª PJ de Goiânia) 
                   07/2016\r\n4ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – INFÂNCIA E JUVENTUDE\r\nAtribuição: Infância e Juventude – Ato Infracional\r\nJuizado da 
Infância e Juventude: (62) 3285-5429/5439; 2º Juizado Cível: (62) 3251-
\r\n6953;\r\n4promotoria@mpgo.mp.br Frederico Augusto de Oliveira Santos 
(Frederico Resolução\r\n                       Augusto de Oliveira Santos atua em 
substituição 08/2016\r\n                       na 52ª Promotoria de Justiça de 
Goiânia)\r\n5ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – FAZENDA 
PÚBLICA\r\nESTADUAL\r\nAtribuição: Cível – 2ª, 3ª Varas da Fazenda Pública 
Estadual (Juiz 1 e 2) e 1º\r\nJuizado Especial da Fazenda Pública.\r\nEdifício-
Sede: sala 157 – ramal: 8232\r\n5promotoria@mpgo.mp.br Eduardo Abdon Moura 
(Eduardo Abdon Moura Resolução\r\n                       atua perante as 3ª, 5ª e 
6ª Varas da Fazenda Pública 12/2018\r\n                       Estadual e no 1º 
Juizado Especial das Fazendas,\r\n                       exclusivamente quanto
 aos feitos relacionados à\r\n                       Fazenda     Pública  
    Estadual,   sem    prejuízo,\r\n                       provisoriamente, até 
ulterior deliberação do egrégio\r\n                       Colégio de Procuradores 
de Justiça – portaria n.\r\n                       2563/18).\r\n6ª PROMOTORIA DE 
JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – FAMÍLIA\r\nAtribuição: Cível – 6ª Vara de 
Família\r\nEdifício-Sede: sala 142-B – ramal: 8214/8468\r\n6promotoria@mpgo.mp.br
 Vaga (Maria Cecilia de Jesus Ferreira responde        Resolução\r\n   
                    pela 6ª PJ de Goiânia, sem prejuízo – portaria n.
     06/2016\r\n                       519/19)\r\n7ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE 
GOIÂNIA – MEIO AMBIENTE E\r\nURBANISMO\r\nAtribuição: Meio Ambiente e 
Urbanismo\r\nEdifício-Sede: sala 147 – ramal: 8460/8585\r\n7promotoria@mpgo.mp.br 
Alice de Almeida Freire                               Resolução\r\n                                                                            015/2013\r\n"
```

That's my desired output (**highlighted**):

2ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – CRIMINAL (RECLUSÃO)\r\nAtribuição: `Criminal – 8ª Vara Criminal (juiz 2)\r\nNovo Fórum: sala 203-B – fone: 3018-0835\r\n2promotoria@mpgo.mp.br  Vanusa de Araújo Lopes Andrade                       Resolução\r\n                                                                             07/2016\r\n3ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – CRIMINAL (RECLUSÃO)\r\n`Atribuição: `Criminal – 10ª Vara Criminal (juiz 2)\r\nNovo Fórum: sala 423 A - Telefones: 3018-0808 / 0809 / 0810 / 0811\r\n3promotoria@mpgo.mp.br Mozart Brum Silva (Mozart Brum Silva atua em Resolução\r\n                       substituição na 64ª PJ de Goiânia)                    07/2016\r\n4ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – INFÂNCIA E JUVENTUDE\r\n`Atribuição: `Infância e Juventude – Ato Infracional\r\nJuizado da Infância e Juventude: (62) 3285-5429/5439; 2º Juizado Cível: (62) 3251-\r\n6953;\r\n4promotoria@mpgo.mp.br Frederico Augusto de Oliveira Santos (Frederico Resolução\r\n                       Augusto de Oliveira Santos atua em substituição 08/2016\r\n                       na 52ª Promotoria de Justiça de Goiânia)\r\n5ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – FAZENDA PÚBLICA\r\nESTADUAL\r\n`Atribuição: `Cível – 2ª, 3ª Varas da Fazenda Pública Estadual (Juiz 1 e 2) e 1º\r\nJuizado Especial da Fazenda Pública.\r\nEdifício-Sede: sala 157 – ramal: 8232\r\n5promotoria@mpgo.mp.br Eduardo Abdon Moura (Eduardo Abdon Moura Resolução\r\n                       atua perante as 3ª, 5ª e 6ª Varas da Fazenda Pública 12/2018\r\n                       Estadual e no 1º Juizado Especial das Fazendas,\r\n                       exclusivamente quanto aos feitos relacionados à\r\n                       Fazenda     Pública      Estadual,   sem    prejuízo,\r\n                       provisoriamente, até ulterior deliberação do egrégio\r\n                       Colégio de Procuradores de Justiça – portaria n.\r\n                       2563/18).\r\n6ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – FAMÍLIA\r\n`Atribuição: `Cível – 6ª Vara de Família\r\nEdifício-Sede: sala 142-B – ramal: 8214/8468\r\n6promotoria@mpgo.mp.br Vaga (Maria Cecilia de Jesus Ferreira responde        Resolução\r\n                       pela 6ª PJ de Goiânia, sem prejuízo – portaria n.     06/2016\r\n                       519/19)\r\n7ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – MEIO AMBIENTE E\r\nURBANISMO\r\n`Atribuição:  `Meio Ambiente e Urbanismo\r\nEdifício-Sede: sala 147 – ramal: 8460/8585\r\n7promotoria@mpgo.mp.br Alice de Almeida Freire           Resolução\r\n                                                                       015/2013\r\n`

**EDITED: I found a solution and posted here**

Comment: Can you explain why the 4th group has to keep the `Juizado Especial da Fazenda Pública.`-part? Because on the third group, `Juizado da Infância e Juventude` has to be skipped. I cannot figure out the logics why..

Comment: I still do not get it... the first `Atribuição:` is waaaay further in the text, after a couple more `\r\n`'s. So why not extract these as well?

Comment: I think I made a mistake in doing this question...you made me see it.
Can I just delete my question?
Thanks!

Comment: You probaply can, but perhaps it is better to edit it?

Comment: anyway, here is a regex-solution that matches the output from the answer by @BrunoPinheiro: `regmatches(teste, gregexpr("(?<=Atribuição: ).*?(?=\\r\\n)", teste, perl=TRUE))[[1]]`, or `stringr::str_extract_all( teste, "(?<=Atribuição: ).*?(?=\\r\\n)")`

Comment: Probably yes, but I still don't know the right question to do!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in regular expressions, so probably you can run this in a not-so-trick way, but with this you get the desired output

```
x <- unlist(strsplit(teste, split = "\\r\\n"))
x <- x[grepl("^Atribuição:" , x) | grepl("^Juizado Especial" , x)]
x <- gsub("\\n", "", x)
x[4] <- paste(x[4], x[5])[-5] # included
x <- gsub(".*: ", "", x)
x
[1] "Criminal – 8ª Vara Criminal (juiz 2)"                                                                   
[2] "Criminal – 10ª Vara Criminal (juiz 2)"                                                                  
[3] "Infância e Juventude – Ato Infracional"                                                                 
[4] "Cível – 2ª, 3ª Varas da Fazenda Pública Estadual (Juiz 1 e 2) e 1º Juizado Especial da Fazenda Pública."
[5] "Juizado Especial da Fazenda Pública."                                                                   
[6] "Cível – 6ª Vara de Família"                                                                             
[7] "Meio Ambiente e Urbanismo"
```

**EDIT**
It's even tricky than the original and not complete solution

Comment: Look that in the 4th object you didn't extract all the content...it should be:
`Cível – 2ª, 3ª Varas da Fazenda Pública Estadual (Juiz 1 e 2) e 1º Juizado Especial da Fazenda Pública.`

Comment: It's true. I made an edition. But it's nothing efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for my own problem:
`str_extract_all(teste, regex("(?<=(Atribuição: ))(.*?)(?=(Atribuição: |^))", dotall = T))`

[[1]]
[1] "Criminal – 8ª Vara Criminal (juiz 2)\r\nNovo Fórum: sala 203-B – fone: 3018-0835\r\n2promotoria@mpgo.mp.br  Vanusa de Araújo Lopes Andrade                       Resolução\r\n                                                                             07/2016\r\n3ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – CRIMINAL (RECLUSÃO)\r\n"
[2] "Criminal – 10ª Vara Criminal (juiz 2)\r\nNovo Fórum: sala 423 A - Telefones: 3018-0808 / 0809 / 0810 / 0811\r\n3promotoria@mpgo.mp.br Mozart Brum Silva (Mozart Brum Silva atua em Resolução\r\n                       substituição na 64ª PJ de Goiânia)                    07/2016\r\n4ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – INFÂNCIA E JUVENTUDE\r\n"
[3] "Infância e Juventude – Ato Infracional\r\nJuizado da Infância e Juventude: (62) 3285-5429/5439; 2º Juizado Cível: (62) 3251-\r\n6953;\r\n4promotoria@mpgo.mp.br Frederico Augusto de Oliveira Santos (Frederico Resolução\r\n                       Augusto de Oliveira Santos atua em substituição 08/2016\r\n                       na 52ª Promotoria de Justiça de Goiânia)\r\n5ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – FAZENDA PÚBLICA\r\nESTADUAL\r\n"
[4] "Cível – 2ª, 3ª Varas da Fazenda Pública Estadual (Juiz 1 e 2) e 1º\r\nJuizado Especial da Fazenda Pública.\r\nEdifício-Sede: sala 157 – ramal: 8232\r\n5promotoria@mpgo.mp.br Eduardo Abdon Moura (Eduardo Abdon Moura Resolução\r\n                       atua perante as 3ª, 5ª e 6ª Varas da Fazenda Pública 12/2018\r\n                       Estadual e no 1º Juizado Especial das Fazendas,\r\n                       exclusivamente quanto aos feitos relacionados à\r\n                       Fazenda     Pública      Estadual,   sem    prejuízo,\r\n                       provisoriamente, até ulterior deliberação do egrégio\r\n                       Colégio de Procuradores de Justiça – portaria n.\r\n                       2563/18).\r\n6ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – FAMÍLIA\r\n"
[5] "Cível – 6ª Vara de Família\r\nEdifício-Sede: sala 142-B – ramal: 8214/8468\r\n6promotoria@mpgo.mp.br Vaga (Maria Cecilia de Jesus Ferreira responde        Resolução\r\n                       pela 6ª PJ de Goiânia, sem prejuízo – portaria n.     06/2016\r\n                       519/19)\r\n7ª PROMOTORIA DE JUSTIÇA DE GOIÂNIA – MEIO AMBIENTE E\r\nURBANISMO\r\n"

So now I'm getting everything beetween the words `Atribuição:`, but excluding the boundaries.